# What is the function of "stein" in "steinreich?"

Tags: word-choice, adjective

In "Die Firma", the German translation of the American novel "The Firm", the partners were described as "steinreich". A back-translation might be something like "filthy rich".

How did "stein" become a modifier of "reich" in such a context? Was it because wealth was at some point (at a much earlier time) held, or measured in stones?

Comment: @KlemensMorbe Gibt es dann auch Menschen, die sandreich sind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "Stein-" ist hier ein (salopp) emotional verstärkendes Präfix.
>   Spätmittelhochdeutsch *steinrīche*: reich an Edelsteinen, sehr/ungewöhnlich reich.
>
> (Duden)

Jedoch steht im [Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/genFOplus.tcl?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS43961) der Gebrüder Grimm unter *steinreich*:

> oft falsch erklärt: 'reich an edelsteinen'
>
> [...]
>
> richtige erklärung schon bei [Adelung](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009134_2_2_2608) 'sehr reich ..., von stein, sofern es oft eine [intension](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Intension) bezeichnet'

Sofern ich mich nicht irre, soll *von Stein* hier das Reichwerden durch den Abbau von/Handel mit Stein bezeichnen. Bei Grimm ist eine Gegend bzw. eine Krone reich an (Edel-)steinen, also steinreich. Bei Dudens Eintrag stellt sich die Frage, ob man einen Menschen auch als *reich an Edelsteinen* bezeichnen kann (*-reich* bedeutet *durch viel von etwas gekennzeichnet*). Meinem Sprachgefühl nach geht das nicht, und Adelungs Erklärung wird von der schon immer dagewesenen [Teure](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT03389) von Stein als Baumaterial gestützt. Siehe dazu noch die letzte Seite dieses [PDF](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/genFOplus.tcl?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS43961).

Laut http://www.dwds.de/?qu=stein- ist *steinreich* seit dem 15. Jahrhundert belegt. Das deckt sich mit der Einordnung ins Spätmittelhochdeutsche von Duden.

*Steinalt* scheint auch den bei Grimm angeführten Beispielen zufolge etwas älter zu sein (16. Jh.).

Älter als *steinreich* ist jedoch *steinhart* (mhd.). Obwohl ich bei weitem kein Adelung bin, stelle ich eine weitere Möglichkeit in den Raum, parallel zur Entwicklung von beispielsweise *ur*:

> uralt        → sehr alt   → sehr hart   → ur hart
>   steinhart → sehr hart → sehr reich → steinreich

Comment: Hast Du eine Quelle zu den letzten Möglichkeiten, oder ist das Deine Spekulation?

Comment: Und ich dachte, das kommt von "Familie Feuerstein", weil da immer stein- und fels- vor allen möglichen Adjektiven stand.;-)

Comment: Bei *"steinalt"* funktioniert das mit den Edelsteinen und dem wertvollen Baustoff nicht - die Grimms haben vermutlich recht, wenn sie sagen, dass diese Erklärung falsch sei. Siehe auch folgende Anregung für ein ergänzendes [edit]: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=stein- und http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Komparation/Elativ.html

Comment: Wahrscheinlich entsprang "steinalt" einem Vergleich mit dem unmenschlich hohen Alter von Steinen.

Comment: Handel mit Stein (Bausteinen, Backstein?) klingt auch nicht plausibler. Mir scheint eher, dass Steine überall rumliegen - man muss sich nur bücken und kann einen Stein vom Boden/Weg/Feld aufheben. Ist aber auch rein spekulativ.

Comment: Der Fachbegriff is 'Elativ' (de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elativ), und er ist heute oft unregelmäßig und muß pro Adjektiv einzeln gelernt werden. Noch eine Flektionshürde für den Fremdsprachler!

Comment: @userunknown Weder Back- noch Bausteine sind *Stein* in dem Sinne. [Naturstein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturstein#Gewinnung_und_Verarbeitung_von_Naturwerkstein) ist gemeint. So ein Haus ist auch heute noch unleistbar (für den Durchschnittsmenschen).

Comment: @userunknown "von einem in jeder hinsicht steinreichen manne aufgeführt, denn seine ... steinbrüche bringen ihm järlich 46000"

Comment: @Carlster Ah, danke!

Comment: @Carlster: Was ist das für ein Pseudozitat, was soll es belegen - dass es mal irgendwann irgendwo einen Mann gab, der irrsinnig reich war? Wenn erst erklärt werden muss, dass Naturstein sonderlich teuer sein kann, dann eignet es sich kaum im Sprichwort - das versteht ja dann keiner.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist kein Pseudozitat, sondern ein echtes Zitat. Ich bezweifle, dass das früher jemandem erklärt werden musste. Ob die Menschen heute den (möglichen) Zusammenhang begreifen, spielt überhaupt keine Rolle für die Etymologie des Wortes. Außerdem handelt es sich hier nicht um ein Sprichwort. Du kannst gerne einen Bearbeitungsvorschlag abgeben, eine eigene Antwort posten oder auch meine downvoten.

Comment: Es ist ein Pseudozitat, weil nicht dabei steht, von wo es stammt, von wem und wann.

Answer (score 3):

In reply to Celtschk: in Dutch you have ‘kei-’ as an intensifier. ‘Kei’ means ‘cobble’ or ‘boulder’ and as an intensifier it started its career in ‘keihard’ = ‘as hard as a cobble’. But ‘hard’ can also mean ‘fast’ in Dutch and ‘keihard’ started to be used in the sense of ‘very fast’ and as a prefix ‘kei-’ started to lose its literal meaning. Nowadays you have words like ‘keigaaf’ = ‘awesome’ which are nonsensical when analysed literally.

I still think that ‘steinreich’ derives from ‘able to afford a stone house’ though.

Comment: And some people say you don't get rep for good comments.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~steinreich%20sein&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou), being *steinreich* meant having a house of stone. Usually houses were built of wood back then, only rich people could afford houses of stone. Nowadays, the prefix *stein* is however often used in the sense of *very* like in *steinalt.* The etymology however might be different there of course.

Comment: I can't think of a use of "stein-" where the meaning cannot be derived from stones; "steinalt" = "old as stones"; stones live very long, and are therefore usually very old. "steinhart" = "hard as stone". Obviously stone is generally very hard. Any counterexample?

Comment: @celtschk I think he is referring to the possibility that *alt* received the prefix *stein-* out of another reason than *reich* did (which seems likely). Although, as Anonymous pointed out, *stein* could have been an established intensifier before being applied to *alt* and *reich*.

Comment: Although indeed possible, I do not think that qualifies as a source. Are you referring to something like this: || der (ein müller) was der steinreichest man, //
daz nye keyn steynreycher dar kwam //
und so steynreiche were  //
alz derselbe müllere. //
haus und hoffe was vol gesteyn //
ander sein reichtuem was gar kleyn, //
davon er der steynreich müller hiesz ||

Comment: Actually your source could rather be interpreted different as the miller in that poem seems to be actually rather poor beside his house. I happened to watch a documentation some time ago giving the upper explanation, but unfortunately cannot find another source for it.

Comment: *Actually*, my second comment resulted from uncareful reading. And yes, the miller is poor :) (in every interpretation)